# Subtract values from the same Column in sql?

Tags: sql, sum, subtraction

[image: Here is my table named records]

```
SELECT SUM(CASE isDeposited WHEN 0 THEN amount WHEN 1 THEN -amount END) AS total
FROM records WHERE memberID = 3;
```

That's my code. I've tried it and it works but didn't give me the right result. 
memberID 3 has a total of 250 - 50 withdraw, which is 200 but it gives me the result of 150.

Comment: memberID 3 has 4 rows with isdeposited=0 and 1 row with isdeposited=1 so 4x50 - 1x50=200-50=150

Comment: @forpas; oh thanks makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in the calculation, `(4 * 50) - 50 = 150.`

Comment: Oh... What im thinking was sum it all up then subtract the 50. Thanks a lot makes sense now 